# How to address/check whether a character in a string isn't a disallowed character?

Tags: python, string, function

To be more specific, if I have a string as such:

```
string = "app-_l#e"
```

Now, all letter, numerical, hyphens, and underscores are allowed; though any other character is not.

Is there a function that would filter out designated types and/or single characters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [str.translate](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_translate.htm) to remove the allowed chars from the string leaving you with an empty string if only allowed chars are in the string or else a string of forbidden chars:

```
from string import ascii_letters, digits

s = "app-_l#e"
# if the string is empty
if not s.translate(None, "-_" + ascii_letters + digits):
    # string only contains allowed characters
```

After translating your input string would look like:

```
In [7]: from string import ascii_letters, digits

In [8]: s = "app-_l#e"

In [9]: s.translate(None, "-_" + ascii_letters + digits)
Out[9]: '#'
```

Or keep a [set](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) of allowed chars:

```
from string import ascii_letters, digits
allowed = set("-_" + ascii_letters + digits)
s = "app-_l#e"
if all(ch in allowed for ch in s):
     # string only contains allowed characters
```

Of you want to find out what forbidden characters are in the string either `print s.translate(None, "-_" + ascii_letters + digits)` which will only have any chars not allowed or iterate in a for loop:

```
from string import ascii_letters, digits
allowed = set("-_" + ascii_letters + digits)
s = "app-_l#e"
disallowed = [ch for ch in s if ch not in allowed]
```

Comment: Thank god I did not add them, else you would have had to re-write all the code again :P

Comment: If you are using sets then use subset op: `set(s) <= allowed`

Comment: @Suor,  creating a set every time would less efficient that simply checking with in

Comment: You mean `allowed.issuperset(s)`?

Comment: @Suor, I mean I would not do anything other than use `in`, creating a set is `0(n)` so what would be the point of calling `set(s)` as opposed to lazily evaluating?

Comment: `set(s) <= allowed` is clearer, less chance to make an error like you did. You also can find `disallowed = set(s) - allowed` very easily.

Comment: @Suor, what error are you talking about? You understand it is less efficient because we are doing a linear scan over s to create the set every time even if the first character is forbidden?

Comment: You used `.issubset()` instead of `.issuperset()` then removed that comment.

Comment: @Suor: That's silly; you can get `<=` wrong just as easily as `issubset`, and you can spot and fix it just as easily either way. Padraic's point isn't about which pair of operators/methods you use, but about which one you setify: only one of the two needs to be a set, while the other can be any iterable, and converting `allowed` makes a lot more sense because you only do that once all program rather than once per string to check.

Comment: There is no real difference in speed unless string is very long, so you shouldn't even speak of efficiency here. And anyway correctness should be considered first.

Comment: @Suor, that was a typo copying from pycharm not a mistake and what @abarnet said hit the nail on the head, also how is <= more readable than `allowed.issuperset(s)`? What is correct about creating a set for no reason?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`re`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html), However note that it will be slower.

```
>>> import re
>>> pat = re.compile(r'[\d|\w|\-|_]+$')
>>> if pat.match("app-_l#e"):
...     print True
... else:
...     print False
... 
False
```

And a matching example

```
>>> if pat.match("apple123_-"):
...     print True
... else:
...     print False
... 
True
```

Comment: You don't need to use `^` in `.match()` it always starts from beginning. Better not use `.match()` at all use `.search()` instead.

Comment: Hey @Suor, thanks for mentioning that. The original intention to use `match` was that it will find that from the starting. But yes `^` is not required. It is quite redundant. Thanks again for your attention. :)